# Can not use keyboard on unity

Tags: unity, keyboard

Dear Ubuntu Community,

currently I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and few hours ago, an update notifier prompted to install an update. After update finished, it ask for system restart, I think there is some kernel update etc.

The problem start after restart, I can type password when login, but after entering unity desktop, my keyboard become suddenly unusable, system doesn't respond to any key press, after few minutes, it lock the screen automatically, but still I can't type password to unlock the screen.

I tried to logout (mouse is working properly), and login again, try starting onscreen keyboard, but still have no luck, system still doesn't respond to the key press.

I tried to login in console, and keyboard working well, tried to install xfce, and keyboard also working properly, keyboard also working properly when login to unity as guest, it only not working when I login using my account.

I also try to reset unity config via `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` , but still no luck

any suggestion to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unity runs as a compiz plugin.

To reset compiz, install donf-tools and run the following

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

I can't think of any accessibility options that would disable the keyboard but you may want to check those as well and if it's a laptop, check the function keys to make sure it's not disabled.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: yeah, that's weird, any key or combination key pressed on keyboard not triggering any event at all, will try to reset compiz

Comment: sorry, but still no change after resetting compiz config :(

maybe I will stuck with xfce for a while

Comment: I ended up with clearing up my home directory, and the keyboard is now working, but need to re-setup everything